# How to use indexed object inside Manipulate so that its state is saved as other dynamics?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a really big problem on my hands.

I spend a week rewriting a Manipulate demo to use indexed objects (to use them as emulation of a struct)

However, when I started I did not know how to define them as `None control` type (so that the state is saved between each Manipulate update), so, I moved them to the Initialization section for now, so that I can test the idea.

Everything works well except for one problem:

In the Initialization section, they become GLOBAL. Which means, when making a demo, and making a snap-shot of the Manipulate, which one must do, then the 2 Manipulates now will interact with each others in an undesired way. They share these global variables (the indexed objects). Which means if I change something in one Manipulate, the other Manipulate is affected.

The WRI demonstration editor do not recommend using global variables inside the Manipulate section either.

I'll explain the problem with simple examples, and hope an expert here might know a work around. Currently I have something like this, which works:

```
Manipulate[
 p@x = 0;  (*I'd like to use here *)
 p@y = 99; (*etc...*)

 foo,
 {{foo, 0, "foo"}, 0, 10, 1},

 Initialization :>
  {
   p[x] = 99;  (*my data live here *)
   p[y] = 0;   (*my data live here *)
  }
 ]
```

But in the above p[x] and p[y] are global. I tried the control None trick, but this does not work:

```
  Manipulate[
     p[x] = 0;
     foo,
     {{foo, 0, "foo"}, 0, 10, 1},
     {{p[x], 99}, None} (* syntax error, what is the correct syntax? *)
     ]
```

I can't put a Module around Manipulate in order to use it to save state. Not allowed.

So, I need a way to have these indexed object preserve the state between each Manipulate update, just like a control variable, but not be global.

But the problem I do not know how to do this. The only way I knew to do this, was using the Control None trick.

I know that Manipulate is basically a `DynamicModule[]` itself. That is why its own variables (control variables) keep state.  I need these indexed object to be like them as well. Can I use a DynamicModule[] inside Manipulate somehow to do this or is there a simple solution to this?

Btw, I found I can do the following

```
Manipulate[
 z,
 {{foo, 0, "foo"}, 0, 10, 1},
 {{z, p[x]}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

But I am not sure what to make of the above. I need to use p@x and not z.

The strange thing, one can define an array of indexed objects, but not a single one?

```
Manipulate[
 z,
 {{foo, 0, "foo"}, 0, 10, 1},
 {{z, Table[p[i], {i, 5}]}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

Thanks for any hints.

**Update:**

I am not able to get Mike answer below to work as I needed it to. For example, suppose I want to have p[x] initialized to 0, and then in each Manipulate update, I want to add one to it. How to do that? This is what I tried:

```
Manipulate[

 DynamicModule[{p, x}, (*not working *)
  p@x = p@x + 1;
  p@x,
  Initialization :>
   {
    p@x = 0;
   }
  ],

 {{n, 0, "n"}, 0, 10, 1},
 TrackedSymbols :> n

]
```

Will keep trying things...

**Update 2:30 AM**

This below is more clear example of the problem in case the above is not clear

```
Manipulate[

 p@x = p@x + 1;(*I'd like to use here*)
 n;
 Row[{"p@x=", p@x}],

 Button["click to update p@x", n++],
 {{n, 0}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {n},
 Initialization :> {
   p@x = 0;
   }
 ]
```

[image]

In this example, an indexed object, p[x] is global variable, hence its state is preserved. I need to do the same, but without having p[x] defined as global, but move it to be part of the Manipulate so that it becomes localized, but also have its state saved.

The problem again, is that the `control None` syntax does not allow me to type

```
{{p@x,0},None}
```

Hope this example makes things more clear.

Comment: I just saw your edits after I posted a possible answer. It seems to me that in both cases you are getting what you should expect to get. You have z as p[x] and display that. You have z as {p[1],p[2],p[3]...} and display that. I don't see the difference.

Comment: "For example, suppose I want to have p[x] initialized to 0, and then in each Manipulate update, I want to add one to it. How to do that?" This implies that you want p@x to change when n changes. Is that correct?

Comment: @Mike, yes. p@x is the same as p[x], just another way of writing it, and I wanted p[x] saved and updated, but without it being global. Please see my 2:30 am edit for a more clear example of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the caveat that I mostly only use DynamicModule, rarely Manipulate, so I'm not familiar with how you torture it into submission, I'm thinking this may work:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{p, x, y},

  p@x = 0;
  p@y = 99;

  p[y]*foo (* or Dynamic[p[x]*foo] *)],

 {{foo, 0, "foo"}, 0, 10, 1}]
```

If it doesn't work the way you require you may need to provide more information or wait for a Manipulate guy to respond.

**Edit**

Just added an alternative with a Dynamic. So in your real code if e.g. p or x or y are to be updated then you need to use Dynamic. (The example above assume x is dynamic)

**FURTHER EDIT**

Your most recent edit implies that you want p@x to change when the value of n changes, e.g. when the slider moves.

```
Manipulate[
DynamicModule[{p, x, tmp},
  p@x = 0;

  {Dynamic[p@x += 1; n, TrackedSymbols :> {n}], Dynamic[p@x]}],

 {{n, 0, "n"}, 0, 10, 1}]
```

That is it for me tonight. Maybe someone else can offer some suggestions.

Comment: thanks, I will go try your method, it seems putting a DynamicModule inside Manipulate works for this simple example. I need to try it on my large Manipulate and see if it breaks things. Will update after testing. I normally like to keep things simple, and just use Manipulate only and nothing else, but I have no choice now.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't get it to work. How to initialize p[x] inside the dynamic module? So that its state is updated? Please see my edit for what I tried.

Comment: You don't need to initialize p because all you seem to be doing -- in this example -- is assigning a value. In your more complex example, if there is more happening then you can initialize just like you do in Manipulate. If you need p to be updating, which is different to needing to initialize, then Dynamic@p is what you need. (In your simple example p isn't really doing anything so doesn't need to be dynamic).

Comment: on more thought, I am not sure that what you have works for me. After all, Manipulate itself is a DynamicModule. So adding another DynamicModule inside it in order to save a state seems redundant. What ever method is used to save p@x inside the inner DynamicModule, I could have used it in Manipulate. So why add another one. In addition, I am still not able to initialize p@x inside DynamicModule. The whole point is to have indexed Objects defined inside Manipulate, and initialized and have their state saved.  If you can show me an example how to do that, will be great.

Comment: I saw your edits. But I am not sure I explained myself clear. Your example still does not save the state of p@x. All what you are doing is multiplying the updated Manipulate control variable (called foo) with 99 each time 'foo' is changed. What I want is to save p@x itself.  So I still do not see how to initialize p@x to zero, and increment its value each time Manipulate is changed.

Comment: I'd like to show you an example but I am unsure what you mean by "initialize p@x". In the example above p[x] and p[y] have definitions and are used in the calculations. I don't think I can be any further help unless you provide real examples. In your toy example nothing changes. So what changes in your real example? Does p change or just the arguments to p?

Comment: ok, my be my initial example was not clear. But all what I want is to used an indexed object as a control none variable so that its state is saved. Please see my new update, with better example. I want to do this example, just as it is, but without using global p@x. Thanks

Comment: Mike: +1 for *"torture it into submission"*. Btw, you don't need the `DynamicModule`. You can introduce dynamic local variables in `Manipulate` using dummy "controllers" `{var, ControlType -> None}` or `{var, None}`. The only difference is that `var` is by default initialized to `0`.

Comment: Hi Simon, I'm aware of ControlType -> None. For me that is a mild interrogation compared to some of the torture of Manipulate to get it to do what is intuitive in DynamicModule. Nasser posts to the demonstrations site so therefore must use Manipulate otherwise I would have suggested a sole DM solution, ...but in that case it would have been apparent that the problem just disappeared if you use only DM.